# Remove arrows from previous and next link

Tags: posts, single

In the wordpress theme I am developing I inserted some code to display links to the previous and next posts which appears at the bottom of each post. The code looks like this..

```
<?php previous_post_link(); ?>
<?php next_post_link(); ?>
```

The problem is that these arrows << and >> appear next to them. Does anyone know how to get rid of them? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You should have to look at what the codex says about

[`previous_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link)

and

[`next_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link)

Both have the same parameters, the first parameter `$format` is the important one to have a look at here

> Format string for the link. This is where to control what comes before and after the link. '%link' in string will be replaced with whatever is declared as 'link' (see next parameter). 'Go to %link' will generate "Go to
>
> Default: `'&laquo; %link'`

If you need to remove the `&laquo;`, you can just simply override it like this

```
<?php previous_post_link('%link'); ?>
```

Comment: @user1181153 Please accept my answer then by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer. Thanks